# Unable to use @ConfigurationProperties in @Scheduled annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using a @ConfigurationProperties to define the property `my.delay`.

```
@ConfigurationProperties( "my" )
public class MyProperties {

    private long delay = 1000L;

    public long getDelay() {
        return delay;
    }
    public void setDelay(long delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }
}
```

In the scheduler method I try to use `my.delay`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties( { MyProperties.class } )
public class TestSprPropApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestSprPropApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled( fixedDelayString = "${my.delay}" )
    public void schedule() {
        System.out.println( "scheduled" );
    }
}
```

Then the following error arises:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'schedule': Could not resolve placeholder 'my.delay' in string value "${my.delay}"
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processScheduled(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:454) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:324) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: can you show your `application.properties` file. You can also inject the property directly to the scheduled annotation.

Comment: @Patrick My `application.properties` is empty. It should use the assigned value from MyProperties and only be overridden if `my.delay` is set in application.properties. At least that's what I intended.

Comment: create a `my.delay=1000` in your property file and it should work. Not sure it the other way is working.

Comment: With the entry in the `application.properties` it works, but to have a default value would be great. How do I inject the suggested property directly in the annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure if there is a solution for your approach. But to simplify your code and also have a default value you can go like that:

No need to have `MyProperty` file at all. You can delete it.

Update your `@Scheduled` annotation with this default value:

```
 @Scheduled( fixedDelayString = "${my.delay:1000}" )
```

This means if Spring does not find a property of `my.delay` it uses the default value after the `:`. In your case its `1000`.

And if you like to override the default value just add the property in your `application.properties` file:

```
my.delay=5000
```

Answer (score 5):

You can solve it using a SpEL expression that [references a bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-bean-references) using `@beanName`.

You would use it that way:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@myProperties.delay}")
```

Notice that `#{}` is used (SpEL expression) instead of `${}` (property placeholder).

Comment: I can't seem to make this work, looks like the SPEL is being evaluated before the `@ConfigurationProperties` bean is evaluated. Is there anything special I should to to have the properties available in the SPEL of the `@Scheduled(fixedDelayString= ?)` annotation?

Comment: @SantiagoBaldrich That requires more info about your project's setup. Please prepare a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) and post a new question, I'm sure someone can help

Comment: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034588/using-configurationproperties-in-a-scheduled-annotation-by-referencing-the-bea