# Using @ConfigurationProperties in a @Scheduled annotation by referencing the bean name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using `@ConfigurationProperties` to configure the delay of a background task in Spring boot and I'm trying to use this value from a `@Scheduled` annotation on another component. However, in order to make it work I must use the full name given to the bean by Spring.

The configuration properties class is as follows:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("some")
class SomeProperties {
    private int millis; //the property is some.millis

    public int getMillis() {
        return millis;
    }

    public void setMillis(int millis) {
         this.millis = millis;
    }
}
```

And I'm using the value as follows in the scheduled method:

```
@Component
class BackgroundTasks {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@'some-com.example.demo.SomeProperties'.millis}") //this works.
    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to reference the value without having to use the full name of the bean? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44024783/1898695) suggests it is possible but I haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `@Component`on the properties class allows to access the property as `"#{@someProperties.persistence.delay}`.

More info in the [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties).

Comment: With the new Spring Boot 2.2.0 it seems you can't use `@Component` anymore. Any idea how to use a short bean name in `@Scheduled`?

Answer (score 4):

> SomePrperties.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@ConfigurationProperties("some")
@Component("someProperties")
public class SomeProperties {

    private int millis; // the property is some.millis

    public int getMillis() {
        return millis;
    }

    public void setMillis(int millis) {
        this.millis = millis;
    }

}
```

> BackgroundTasks.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BackgroundTasks {

    /**
     * 
     * Approach1: We can inject/access the property some.millis directly in @Value
     * fashion even though we have configured it to bind with SomeProperties class
     * using @ConfigurationProperties.
     * 
     * 
     */
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${some.millis}")
    public void fromDirectInjection() {

        System.out.println("Hi, I'm  from DirectInjection method");

    }

    /**
     * 
     * Approach2: Add @Component on SomeProperties and access the bean bean's
     * property millis like below using Spring Expression language
     * 
     * 
     */
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{@someProperties.millis}")
    public void fromConfigurationProperty() {
        System.out.println("Hi, I'm from ConfigurationProperty method");

    }

}
```

> DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

> application.properties

```
some.millis=2000
```

> Version Used

```
 SpringBoot 2.6.0
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

> Output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.6.0-SNAPSHOT)

2021-10-08 08:38:03.342  INFO 8092 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 14.0.2 on TO-GZ9M403-L with PID 8092 (D:\workspaces\configprop\demo (1)\demo\target\classes started by D1 in D:\workspaces\configprop\demo (1)\demo)
2021-10-08 08:38:03.345  INFO 8092 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-10-08 08:38:04.884  INFO 8092 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-10-08 08:38:04.902  INFO 8092 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-10-08 08:38:04.902  INFO 8092 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
2021-10-08 08:38:05.050  INFO 8092 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-10-08 08:38:05.050  INFO 8092 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1631 ms
2021-10-08 08:38:05.644  INFO 8092 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
Hi, I'm  from DirectInjection method
Hi, I'm from ConfigurationProperty method
2021-10-08 08:38:05.662  INFO 8092 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 2.995 seconds (JVM running for 3.712)
Hi, I'm  from DirectInjection method
Hi, I'm from ConfigurationProperty method
Hi, I'm  from DirectInjection method
Hi, I'm from ConfigurationProperty method
Hi, I'm  from DirectInjection method
Hi, I'm from ConfigurationProperty method
```

Comment: @Tobias Kremer  The same sample project- https://github.com/arunsai271/scheduler_fixedratestring for your reference.

Comment: I start to see what my problem is. This does not work with constructor binding. So only with mutable properties. I believe mutability is rarely wanted here. Hm..

Comment: If possible please post a sample example class with how you are binding

Answer (score 4):

from [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.enabling-annotated-types):

> When the @ConfigurationProperties bean is registered using configuration property scanning or via @EnableConfigurationProperties, the bean has a conventional name: -, where  is the environment key prefix specified in the @ConfigurationProperties annotation and  is the fully qualified name of the bean. If the annotation does not provide any prefix, only the fully qualified name of the bean is used.
> The bean name in the example above is com.example.app-com.example.app.SomeProperties.

So the answer boils to:

- if you use JavaBean style properties you can register bean with @Component or @Bean. Then you can use just the bean name in SPEL expression
- if you use @ConstructorBinding to have immutable properties then you have to use fully qualified bean name with the enviroment key prefix like this:

`@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{@'other-com.example.demo.OtherProperties'.millis}")`

Here is sample project - https://github.com/marksutic/scheduler_fixedratestring, forked from Arun Sai

Answer (score 1):

Following should work fine assuming bean is created with `someProperties` by default and name is not overridden.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@someProperties.getMillis()}")
```

Comment: The problem is that if you use @ConfigurationProperties this does not work.
While you can get your properties injected in may places, this does not work here.

Comment: Add @Configuration along with ConfigurationProperties. That will create the bean.