# How to autowire @ConfigurationProperties bean into SpEL expression in spring-boot 2.2.*?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 2.2.6 and as [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-enabling) says:

> When the `@ConfigurationProperties` bean is registered using configuration property scanning or via `@EnableConfigurationProperties`, the bean has a conventional name: `<prefix>-<fqn>`, where `<prefix>` is the environment key prefix specified in the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation and `<fqn>` is the fully qualified name of the bean. If the annotation does not provide any prefix, only the fully qualified name of the bean is used.
>
> The bean name in the example above is acme-com.example.AcmeProperties.

However when I use this SpEL: `@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@(mr-my.config.properties.ApplicationProperties).task.get(T(my.config.Constants).CONST).delay}")` I am getting an error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in my.controllers.Controller required a bean named 'mr' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'mr' in your configuration.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034588/using-configurationproperties-in-a-scheduled-annotation-by-referencing-the-bea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The prefix supplied to the `ConfigurationProperties` annotation is the name of the bean.

For example:

```
package com.my.company;

...

@ConfigurationProperties("alpha.beta.gamma")
public class TheTimes {

    private Duration theInterval = Duration.ofSeconds(30);

    // getter and setter
}
```

and then

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@'alpha.beta.gamma-com.my.company.TheTimes'.theInterval}")
```

Comment: Fantastic answer - AFAICT this is not documented anywhere or at least not easily grokkable - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@(mr-my.config.properties.ApplicationProperties).task.get(T(my.config.Constants).CONST).delay}")
```

`@` means you need to provide a bean with the given name.

```
@Configuration
class SchedulerConfig{

 @Bean
  public String scheduler1Delay() {
     return "500000s";
  }
}
```

Now set the bean name in the configuration as

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@scheduler1Delay}")
```